# Sending test emails in development without spam or rejection issues

Tags: .net, windows

I run my development environment in a VM and need to test the delivery and appearance of emails from my applications.  The problem is when my SMTP server starts delivering a lot of mail to my corporate email account, the server is soon rejected as a source of spam.  Of course, the major Internet email providers will also never accept email from such a server.

One solution with a problem:
I've delivered to a to a file folder using the .NET SpecifiedPickupDirectory option and open in outlook express, but the problem is that VALID images always display as broken images.

Comment: It doesn't really sound it's the same problem with your two paragraphs.  Broken images are due to one kind of reasons, and spamming filters on servers are something else.

Comment: As one partial solution to my problem, I've delivered emails to a specified pickup directory instead of sending them over the network.  It writes these as .eml files.  These are formatted is such a way that when you open them in outlook, valid images are not displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer: [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP/), an open source pseudo-SMTP test server. This is the ultimate dev email testing app that is a must have.

Comment: The link is dead, RIP. But here is a free open-source fakeSMTP server that works just as well. https://github.com/Nilhcem/FakeSMTP

Comment: I updated the Papercut URL. Goodbye codeplex (heh), hello Github. There is also a marketing site at https://www.papercut-smtp.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could do quite a lot of your email scenarios using unit tests and a mock mailer implementation.  For example, you can create an interface for and a wrapper around the SmtpClient class.  This wrapper should implement the interface.  Use dependency injection to provide the dependent SmtpWrapper class (as the interface) to the class that uses it.  In your unit tests, you can supply a mock instance of the interface to the class under test and ensure that it is correctly sending the messages that you expect to the recipients that you expect given the set up of the test.

Eventually, you will have to run some integration tests, but probably much fewer.  In your integration tests you can you use your test SMTP server.  Given that most of your tests are run in unit testing with your mock implementation, this might be enough to keep your corporate mail server from misidentifying your test server.

Comment: +1 Completely agreed, developer should not test mail delivery. He should test only the fact that the message is sent.

Format of the resulting emails can be tested without actually sending them.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your email being flagged as spam, you will have to talk to the system administrators that administer the corporate email servers. They are in control of how spam is flagged in the system and may be able to exclude your emails.

You are mention an issue with broken images, but this has nothing to do with spam and would perhaps be better as a question of its own (with appropriate title).

Comment: Controlling spam settings on the corporate server is not an option in my situation.

The broken images problem is directly related to one solution I tried.  It is not a problem with broken images, but a problem with the way .eml files are formatted and displayed in outlook when using the .net SMTP SpecifiedPickupDirectory option.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Post Hoc, you can simulate the sending of any amount of email, but the email never leaves your host.  I run this in a VM, and the email stays in the VM.  There is no issue with hitting any spam limits.  There is no limit to the number of addresses you send to.  It then offers a user interface for inspecting the email that was send.  Open source freely available:

Git Hub at:  [Git Hub Site](https://github.com/agilepro/posthoc)

Also see the blog post: [PostHoc: Testing Apps that Send Email](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/posthoc-testing-apps-that-send-email/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like Mailnest.io to get all your test emails in one place. By this way you can be sure that the domain won't be blacklisted as well as accidentally no emails will be sent out to customers. Also it will be easier for your developers and testers to collaborate on email testing.